# Doctrine ORM geting foreign entity by non primary key

Tags: mysql, doctrine

I am trying to reference foreign entity by no primary key

I have a table I may not alter due to compatibility reason and other out of my control. It is a simple locale/country with primary auto increment, unique code like **'us'** and other non-relevant fields.

There was no doctrine on the project until now and some of the tables in the project reference this by **id**, some by **code**

I would like to reference this entity like this:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country", referencedColumnName="code")
     *
     *  @var Country
     */
    private $countryEntity;
```

some other entities do use **id** instead. I cannot use `@ORM\Id` on both as I would need both to query it. I do not want to use second query to fetch **Country** entity. I need to preserve both **id** and **code**.

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL and the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference another table by a non primary key field.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#join-columns-with-non-primary-keys

You should migrate your database to use the primary key in all the relations with the country table.

You can migrate your data with a query like this ine

```
UPDATE target_table SET country_id = (SELECT id FROM country WHERE country.code = target_table.country_entity_code);
```

Comment: This is not what I can do as many other tables depend on **country** in the target_table. I don't want to maintain two columns. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you shoudn't maintain two columns. You need to migrate your database schema and your application to use the primary key of the country table. You should decide if you want to use an auto generated id or the country code as your primary key.